# How to set color to particular static listitem onCreate so that it would look like en empty space

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains HashMap data. My total list items are 4 and are static. As per UI requirement listview needs one empty space after two list items. but i am not sure how can i do that. Currently what am i doing now is putting one empty HashMap string and setting color for that area. Its working but its working on click...How can i set default color for that particular list item onCreate. I was told by some one to try "Setfocusable" but not sure how to use that by getting View onCreate ? Suggestions are welcome

HashMap onCreate where m setting empty string to create that gap look like listitem

```
HashMap<String, String> emptyspace = new HashMap<String, String>();
emptyspace.put(MAIN_FIELD, getString(R.string.emptyspace));
            emptyspace.put(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, null);
```

Inside OnClickListItem method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

else if (position == EMPTYSPACE) { 
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7EBEE"));
                    }

});
```

Regards

Comment: are you using customadapter for listview??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `v.setEnabled(false)` where you don't want to do anything on `onClick`. You will also need to call `v.setEnabled(true)` in the other `View` where you want to the user to be able to click.

Comment: Apoorv - Thanks...But onClick is not an issue here as there is nothing to do onClick . I was looking to set color for that particular listitem. Now it is working coz i am putting on onItemClick. Is there anyway i can do this onCreate... (I mean right when focus comes)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not implementing your own Adapter, do so. Do what you are doing now in onitemClick()(changing the background color based on position) inside getView() method.